# Replace all attributes in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have many cs files, with the next annotation:

```
[Js(Md.pr, imo = false, tr="csc")]
```

where the `tr` value is changed between each `cs` file.

I want to delete all these annotation automaticlly. So I try to use "replace all" in Visual studion, when I choose regular expressions function. So I wrote:

```
find what: [Js*]
replace with ''
```

and It finds many characters in the code, which I don't want to delete.

How can I do it?

Comment: Note that vs2010 has non-standard regexes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Note that C# programmers call those **attributes**; Java programmers call them **annotations**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're are looking for the following regex:

```
\[Js.*\]
```

The char [ is a special char in regex, so it has to be escaped.

`\[` = [

`.` = Matches any single character except a line break.

`*` = Matches zero or more occurrences of the preceding expression, and makes all possible matches.

More information surf to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expression.

```
\[Js\b(.*?)\)\]
```

while find and replace.